# Criteria for a morphism to be etale in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, positive-characteristic

Are there any criteria for a morphism (as nice as you wish) in characteristic p to be etale that relates to the differential map on the associated sheaves of differentials or tangent spaces? I know this is a little vague but I encourage you to post any criterion that looks even a little related!

As an example, I think there is a criterion that a finitely presented schemes is etale if and only if the relative frobenius is an isomorphism. Is there a version of this for maps to be etale?

Comment: By [Stacks Project, Lemma 37.57.15 (tag 0F6W)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F6W), the relative Frobenius is an isomorphism for any *weakly* étale morphism in characteristic $p$. So in particular, the relative Frobenius being an isomorphism isn't sufficient for a morphism to be étale, since there are weakly étale morphisms that aren't étale. Is this is the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I am rather looking for "easy to check" (essentially linear algebra) statements that imply a morphism being etale. So even the relative frob iso might not be easy to check in my case - it would be really great is some condition about the frobenius on the tangent spaces for instance implied etaleness.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think condition (8) of [Stacks Project, Lemma 29.36.15 (tag 02GU)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GU) might be what you're looking for? At least if you're willing to restrict to morphisms locally of finite presentation. There's no restriction on the characteristic for this, either.

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of thing I am looking for but I really want something that's easier to check in char p! Thanks anyway